# @WebMvcTest with @Import does not work. Test context always asks for @Repository beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Using Spring Boot `2.7.3` I can not create a simple integration test for my API using `@WebMvcTest`.

Here is my setup:

```
// GameServerApplicationTests.kt
@SpringBootTest
class GameServerApplicationTests {
    @Test
    fun contextLoads() { }
}
```

```
// CraftService.kt
@Service
class CraftService {
    fun getAll(): List<String> {
        return listOf("foo", "bar")
    }
}
```

```
// CraftApiTest.kt
@WebMvcTest
@Import(value = [CraftService::class])
class CraftApiTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun `should do accept craft all endpoint`() {
        val response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/craft/all", String::class.java)
        assertThat(response.statusCode).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

When I run the test I see this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository' defined in com.gameserver.item.ItemRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on GameServerApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3fba233d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3fba233d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

I have no idea why it is looking for the `itemRepository` bean at all. I never asked for that.

I then added this

```
@WebMvcTest
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = [ComponentScan.Filter(Repository::class)]) // <<
@Import(value = [CraftService::class])
```

Which resulted in this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerRepository' defined in com.gameserver.player.PlayerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on GameServerApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#30c1da48' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#30c1da48': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Which confuses me even more. I explictly excluded all `@Repository` beans - but it just skipped `ItemRepository` and then asked for `PlayerRepository` now.

I am totally lost and have no idea why I am not able to setup a simple integration test for my API endpoint.

EDIT #1:

Other tests run just fine:

[image]

EDIT #2:

I tried to use a `@Configuration` bean for `@Import`.

```
// CraftApiTestConfiguration
@Configuration
class CraftApiTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun getCraftService(): CraftService {
        return CraftService()
    }
}
```

```
// CraftApiTest.kt
@WebMvcTest
@Import(CraftApiTestConfiguration::class)
class CraftApiTest { // ... }
```

That did not help either. It just gave me the second exception mentioned above (the one asking for `playerRepository`)

Comment: Are you sure, the exception is raised while trying to run `CraftApiTest`? Also when you use `@Import` annotation you shouldn't pass a bean class into it, you're supposed to use `@Configuration` annotated classes...

Comment: Yes I am running multiple tests and that's the one that always fails. I replaced the @Import with a `@Configuration` bean now that exposes `@Bean` for `ClientService` now. In this case the second exception I posted in the thread occurs - that one where the `playerRepository` is missing. Therefore unfortunately not fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer although without seeing the actual code it might not be correct.

So `@WebMvcTest` loads a "slice" of your application with all the beans annotated with `@RestControllers`. It doesn't load `@Service` or `@Repository` annotated beans.

When you run the test with `@WebMvcTest` annotation it will load all the controllers, and if, by accident the controller references others than the reference on the service (here I can't say for sure what it is), you might end up loading the stuff that you don't actually need.

Now when you use `@WebMvcTest` there are two things you can/should do:

1. Work with MockMvc instead of rest template that queries a web server, its not a full-fledged web layer test anyway.
2. Try using `@WebMvcTest` with your controller only:

```java
@WebMvcTest(CraftApisController.class)
```

Also instead of injecting the real implementation of service, you can use `@MockBean` so that the real service implementation will be covered by a regular unit test (without spring at all, just plain JUnit/Mockito) and this test could check that your annotations are defined correctly